# Combining static code to my dynamic code. (Based on what I'm fetching in DB)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making a matchmaking system where **2 players will be joined in 1 array if they have the same weight**. **My target is to combine my static code in to my dynamic code**. The snippet I provide is my static code, **it means that the data is not from DB**. It works perfectly. However, when **I'm combining my static code into my dynamic code, it is not working anymore**. The second set of codes I provided below is a **dynamic codes**, **it means that the data is based on what I'm fetching in DB**. Any suggestions on how can I make it work? Been stuck for days. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

[image]

This is static code that works perfectly:

```js
const source = [{
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: 'player1',
    weight: 1,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: 'player2',
    weight: 1,
   
  },
  {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: 'player3',
    weight: 2,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: 'player4',
    weight: 2,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 5,
    entryName: 'player5',
    weight: 3,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 6,
    entryName: 'player6',
    weight: 3,
   
  },
  { 
    entryID: 7,
    entryName: 'player7',
    weight: 1,
  
  },
  { 
    entryID: 8,
    entryName: 'player8',
    weight: 1,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 9,
    entryName: 'player9',
    weight: 1,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 10,
    entryName: 'player10',
    weight: 1,

  },



  ]


  const combine = (source) => {
    return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr.weight]) {
        const levelArr = acc[curr.weight];
        const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
        if (last.length === 2) {
          levelArr.push([curr])
        } else {
          last.push(curr)
        }
      } else {
        acc[curr.weight] = [
          [curr]
        ];
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})
  };


  var result = combine(source)
  var html = ""
  var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there are more than one keys i.e : 2..

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {

    val.forEach(function(value, index) {

     
        var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
        var handlers = index == 0 ? "handlerM[]" : "handlerW[]"
        var weights = index == 0 ? "weightM[]" : "weightW[]"
        html += `<input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${value.entryID}"> 
                 <input type="text" name="${handlers}" value="${value.entryName}">
                 <input type="text" name="${weights}" value="${value.weight}">
                 `
    })
    })
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

This is my dynamic code (It is not working. My target output is the same as the output above). The data I'm fetching are based on Database.

ajax and script:

```
let ajaxResult = []; // the pushed data will be saved here
let save_method;
let table;
let base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

let result = [];
var html = "";



// this is the part where I'm having a hard time to solve. My target is to combine my static code here in this dynamic part. When the condition is met, the result will be the same as above
    const combine = (source) => {

    return source[0].data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
       const [entryID, eventID,  entryName, weight] = curr;
        if (acc[curr.weight]){
         
        const levelArr = acc[curr.weight];
        const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
           if(last.length === 2) {
           levelArr.push[{},{}]
        
            } else {
             last.push(curr)
            }
        }else{
            acc[weight] = [{
                eventID,
                entryID,
                entryName,
                weight
            }];
            }
        return acc; 
    }, {})
}
//end of script matching when 2 players have the same weight.



$(document).ready(function() {
    //datatables
    table = $("#table1").DataTable({


        processing: false,
        serverSide: true,
        order: [],
        searching: false,
        paging: false,
        info: false,

        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/fetch_players')?>",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",

             success: function(data) {
                
                ajaxResult.push(data); // I'm pushing my data to my ajaxResult variable
                result = combine(ajaxResult); // Cleanup your data here. 
                console.log(combine(ajaxResult));

 var keys = Object.keys(combine(ajaxResult)) //if there more then one keys i.e : 2..
                
 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log("Keys " + keys[i])
  //loop through json array
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val, index) {
  //check if index value is `0`..change name. 
    var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
    var handlers = index == 0 ? "handlerM[]" : "handlerW[]"
    var weights = index == 0 ? "weightM[]" : "weightW[]"
    html += `<span> entryID </span><input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${val.entryID}" readonly> &nbsp; 
    <span> Handler </span><input type="text" name="${handlers}" value="${val.entryName}" readonly> &nbsp;
    <span> Weight </span><input type="text" name="${weights}" value="${val.weight}" readonly>
     <span> eventID </span><input type="text" name="eventID[]" value="${val.eventID}" readonly>
      <br>`
  })
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div
                
               
              
                

            },
        },

        "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0], //first column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },
            {
                "targets": [-1], //last column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },

        ],
    });
});
```

Comment: Hit F12, any errors in the console? It's not clear from your question, are you stuck on returning the right data from the server or working with the data on the client?

Comment: Did you check if `result` have correct value return from combine ? Did you see `console.log("Keys " + keys[i])` output inside your browser console ?

Comment: @Swati I did console log and this is the result. https://prnt.sc/17en5wt 

Matt. It has no error when i'm doing f12. Yes, i'm stuck on returning the right data from the server. My dynamic code console log should be the same result with my static code console log

Comment: Your data which is return from server is JSON Array or not ? If its json array you don't need to push that inside different array directly send that json to your combine function.

Comment: I'm returning a json array. https://prnt.sc/17erl9h << This is how i return it.

Comment: Then don't push that inside `[]` because then your structure becomes `[[{},{}]]` but , according to your code you just need `[{},{}...]` .

Comment: Am I in the right path? I've tried several ways beside from your suggestion. And nothing works. This is the result of your suggestion. https://prnt.sc/17flbye  I'm really sorry for troubling you. x.x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234331/discussion-between-swati-and-dark).

Comment: i cannot access the chat anymore. x.x I wonder what happened.

Comment: Yes, i am as well getting connection problem :P

Comment: X.X that made me nervous. I added the response in my post. Take a look if it's okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @swati

```
const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.weight]) {
      const levelArr = acc[curr.weight];
      const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
      if (last.length === 2) {
        levelArr.push([curr])
      } else {
        last.push(curr)
      }
    } else {
      acc[curr.weight] = [
        [curr]
      ];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
};

             result = combine(data.data2);
console.log(result)
var keys = Object.keys(result)
                
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {

    val.forEach(function(value, index) {
```

Made some changes with my controller also on how i fetched my data.